# CoreAudio creating 32-bit float aif file in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-lion, core-audio, core-foundation

Could not find nor figure out what would be the proper 
**.mFormatFlags** flag for successfully creating a 32-bit float linear PCM **aif** (actually aifc) file by means of

```c
AudioFileCreateWithURL (url, 
                        outfileType, 
                        &streamFormat, 
                        kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, 
                        &outfile)
```

where streamFormat is of type AudioStreamBasicDescription. For creating outfileType **kAudioFileCAFType** file the

```c
    streamFormat.mFormatFlags =
kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved;
```

works as expected, but for creating outfileType **kAudioFileAIFCType** the *unsupported format error* is returned. I understand this has to do with endianness issues - in OSX "native endian" Float32 aif isn't supported but only "big endian". **CalculateLPCMFlags** utility also gave no result.

By trial-and-error I discovered the flag setting which does not return format error:

```
outFormat.mFormatFlags =
kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian;
```

Still, there is the "dreaded"   byte-swapping issue, which I'm not sure how to fix if audio bytes are passed wrapped in NSData:

```c
    if(outfileType == kAudioFileAIFCType){
    Float32 valA;
    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < size; i += sizeof(Float32)){
        memmove((void*)&valA, data.bytes +i, sizeof(Float32));       
        Float32 valB = CASwapFloat32HostToBig(*valA);
        memmove((void*)data.bytes + i, &valB, sizeof(Float32));
    }
}
```

For some reason this does nothing. I suspect making some trivial mistake. Can someone please advise fixing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use `ExtAudioFile` and let it handle the conversions?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. No real need for using the complicated ExtAudioFile API, I would have already used it if there was any CODEC-level number crunching required. There's no real data conversion math going on since all data is LPCM, also no rate conversion - just byte swapping which should work because the math behind it is OK.

Comment: **Resolved:** The problem turns out to be an issue of interaction with the compiler. Upon clean rebuilding of all objects and targets with Xcode, the code works as expected.